# Python lex - TypeError: Unknown text

Tags: python, lex

I'm trying to write a simple lex parser. The cope is currently:

```
from ply import lex

tokens = (
      'COMMENT',
      'OTHER'
  )

  t_COMMENT = r'^\#.*\n'

  t_OTHER = r'^[^\#].*\n'

  def t_error(t):
      raise TypeError("Unknown text '%s'" % (t.value,))

  lex.lex()

lex.input(yaml)
  for tok in iter(lex.token, None):
      print repr(tok.type), repr(tok.value)
```

But is fails to parse simple input file:

```
    # This is a real comment
    #And this one also

    #/*
    # *
    # *Variable de feeu
    # */
    ma_var: True

    It is done, over, kaput
```

With the following output:

```
l
'COMMENT' '# This is a real comment\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser_adoc.py", line 62, in <module>
    main2()
  File "parser_adoc.py", line 57, in main2
    for tok in iter(lex.token, None):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ply/lex.py", line 384, in token
    newtok = self.lexerrorf(tok)
  File "parser_adoc.py", line 44, in t_error
    raise TypeError("Unknown text '%s'" % (t.value,))
TypeError: Unknown text '#And this one also

#/*
# *
# *Variable de feeu
# */
ma_var: True

this is done
'
```

So in summary, I defined 2 regex:

- One for line beginning with `#`
- One for lines beginning not with `#`

But it's not working.
I don't understand what's wrong with my regex.

Could you help?

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python regexes (which PLY uses), `^` refers to the beginning of the string, not the beginning of the line, unless multi-line mode has been set. So since both of your rules start with `^`, they can only match on the first line.

You could fix this by wrapping your regexes in `(?m:...)`, which enables multi-line mode, but that's not even necessary here. Instead you can just remove the `^` from the beginning of your rules and it will work as you intend. Since both of your rules always match the entire line, the next token will always start at the beginning of the line - no need to anchor them.